# How to find PID of a while loop?

Tags: shell, process

I run this command in Bash terminal

```
  while [ 0 ]; do 
    i=1; 
    echo $i; 
  done
```

Before running this loop, in another tab of gnome-terminal I did

```
$ps aux | wc -l
192
```

While the loop is still running, I again did

```
$ps aux | wc -l
192
```

My questions -

1. Why the while loop does not seem to get a PID?
2. How to get the PID of individual commands being run inside a while loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `while` does not get its own PID because it's a shell keyword, not an external command. You will get the PID listed as `bash` process. To get the PID, insert `echo $$` inside `while` loop and use `ps aux | grep '[b]ash'` to match the PID.
2. If any command is not a shell builtin you can get the PID using usual manner e.g. using `ps`, `pgrep`. In the PPID (Parent Process ID) field you would normally see the shell PID on which it is running.

   For example. to get details about command `foobar` inside a shell loop, you can do:

   ```
   ps -ef | grep '[f]oobar'
   ```

   or

   ```
   ps aux | grep '[f]oobar'
   ```

   or `pgrep`:

   ```
   pgrep 'foobar'
   ```

   As more than one shell process will be running you should go for verbosity and check the PPID field to match the shell PID.

   Note that as you are looping, the availability of any process in the process table will depend on the time for which it is being run and when you are checking the process table.

Comment: just `ps -Cbash` should do the trick.

Comment: Why '[f]oobar' instead of simply foobar? It's a beautiful trick I wasn't aware of so that grep doesn't print itself from the process listing :)

Comment: “Because it's a keyword” or “because it's a builtin” doesn't automatically imply that it doesn't start a separate process. Some shell syntax does create subprocesses.

Answer (score 1):

`while` and `echo` are built-in bash shell commands - they don't get a separate PID.  Try adding the command `sleep 1` to your list of commands.  Then, you'll see a new command in `ps`.